# Too few items for RecyclerView on screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm making an API call `getData(forPage: Int): Response` which  returns a page-worth of data (10 items max) and `thereIsMoreData: Boolean`.

The recyclerView is implemented that by scrolling, the scroll listener automatically fetches more data using that API call:

```
val scrollListener = object : MyScrollListener() {
        override fun loadMoreItems() {
            apiFunctionForLoading(currentPage + 1)
        }
}
```

The problem is that with longer screen devices that have more space for items (let's say 20), the RV receives 10 items and then doesn't allow scrolling, because there's no more items to scroll to. Without scrolling, more data cannot be loaded.

My naive solution:

1. load first set of data
2. if `thereIsMoreData == true` I load another page of data
3. now I have more data than the screen can display at once hence allowing scroll

Is there a more ellegant solution?

Comment: So as the list scrolls you make the API call? Don't you have any checks to know if the recycler view has reached the end of the current list and then make the API call to fetch more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has this [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) now which is about displaying chunks of data and fetching more when needed. I haven't used it and it looks like it might be a bit of work, but maybe it's worth a look?

Codepath [has a tutorial on using it](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Paging-Library-Guide) and I think their stuff is pretty good and easy to follow, so maybe check that out too. They also have this [older tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) that's closer to what you're doing (handling it yourself) so there's that too.

I guess in general, you'd want your adapter to return an "infinite" number for `getItemCount()` (like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). And then in your `onBindViewHolder(holder, position)` method you'd either set the item at `position`, or if you don't have that item yet you load in the next page until you get it.

That way your initial page will always have the right amount of content, because it will be full of `ViewHolder`s that have asked for data - if there's more than 10, then item 11 will have triggered the API call. But actually handling the callback and all the updating is the tricky part! If you have that working already then great, but it's what the Paging library was built to take care of for you (or at least make it easier!)

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way would be to check whether the view **can** actually scroll down:

```
recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)
```

`1` means downwards -> returns true if it is possible tro scroll down.

So if it returns false, your page is not fully filled yet.

Comment: They're using an API call so it could be streaming data in on-demand

Comment: @Le did this help?